# Contradiction between $a_0$ and $a_k$ for Fourier Series

Tags: analysis, fourier-series

I need to calculate the Fourier Series for the function $f(x) = |x| \; f:[-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$

When calculating $a_k = {1 \over \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \cos{(kx)} dx \; (k \in \mathbb{N_0})$ I get the following formula:

$a_k = \begin{cases} 
0                  & k \; even \\
-{4 \over \pi k^2} & k \; odd
\end{cases}$

Doesn't that mean that $a_0 = 0$ ?

However when I calculate $a_0$ with aboves formula I get:

$a_0 = {2 \over \pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} x dx = \pi$

So what am I missing?

Comment: You didn't show *how* you computed the $a_k$ - you probably assumed $k\neq 0$ somewhere, and hence your formula for $a_k$ isn't value for $k=0$. It's easy to see that $a_0$ cannot be zero here btw - you're integrating a strictly positive function ($\cos(nk) = 1$ for $k=0$!) over a non-empty interval...

Comment: Somewhere in the computation of the integrals you divided by $k$, if $k=0$...

Comment: @fgp Found it in my calculations where I assumed k not to be 0. But can you elaborate on your last sentence? Seems there is something obvious that I am missing?

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes For $k=0$ you're left with $\int \limits_\pi^{-\pi}f$ where $f$ lies strictly above $x$-axis, thus the integral must be positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything, you should think of $a_0$ as an DC value of a signal and all the proceeding components of $a_k$ bring you the periodical behavior with some frequency, you calculated everything ok, but the idea of calculating $a_0$  separately does have a reason. What is the Fourier series of the following two functions:

$f(x)=1+cosx$

$f(x)=cosx$

Only difference is in the DC value - that is in factor $a_0$!

Comment: Its probably better to refer to it as "constant" as opposed to DC, unless you happen to be teaching an Electrical Engineering course.